# Why didn't Germany bomb the crap out of Stalingrad to win the city?

Tags: world-war-two, stalingrad

Why didn't the Germans bomb Stalingrad to the ground and destroy everything in it?  Did the Russians have underground bunkers to stay alive?  How did the Russians survive the bombardment?

Comment: What did your preliminary research show? Did you read any books or articles about the battle of Stalingrad?

Comment: They did. That was one of the reasons why they had so much difficulty conquering the city. Rubble makes for excellent defensive positions.

Comment: See [Bombing of Stalingrad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombing_of_Stalingrad).

Answer (score 1):

The axis (mostly Germans) did bomb Stalingrad. A lot of cities were on fire and the water and electricity grids were out. By the end of the battle, almost the whole city was destroyed, but some buildings were still standing, so the Soviet soldiers probably hid in those buildings. But I'm not sure about that.

Air-raid shelters were not common in the city for its population, so almost everybody needed to stay out in the open.

[Main source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Stalingrad) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombing_of_Stalingrad)

Comment: It's rare for an authoritative answer to contain the phrase "But I'm not sure about that."

Comment: @SteveBird True. I wanted to add that but wanted to make sure people didn't take that as fact.